# What is the advantage of using the LIKE clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to creat a dictionary web site, and i want to know which one will be better for search in my dictionary:

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col='anything'
```

OR

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%anything%'
```

which one have a more speed and prformance? (for only exactly match word)
tnx

Comment: it depends upon on how you want your search function need to work??

Comment: First one will be faster, but it wont do the same. `%anything%` will find anything that contains `%anything%` while `anything` only will find exact match.

Comment: I have a list of English words and i want search in them, What do you recommend ?

Comment: Example : like '%an%' will search anyword which contains an.. so it took a lot more time than simple col='anything'

Comment: I want only exactly match word !!! What do you recommend now?

Comment: Search for sargability

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. If you want to "*exactly match word*" the ```LIKE``` clause you posted doesn't work. Thus it is irrelevant which one is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column `col` is index , then using the first query will use the index

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col='anything'
```

And in the 2nd case even if the column `col` is indexed optimizer will not be able to use the index.

So the first query would be better in performance.

Check out more about query optimization

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: I asked a question about [sorting the result of query when there is `union all`] and *(I think)* you wrote an answer for me. (I asked that question with another account and that account is removed now). So I can not find your answer, can you find it? (also I remember you used of `@variables` in your solution) tnx

Comment: ouch I cant really find that ! Since I gave a lot of such answers which involves usage of mysql variables.

Comment: well, I asked that question again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166093/how-to-sort-the-result-of-multiple-queries-alternatively), if you have some free time, please take a look at it, because I just need to that answer you have gave me already.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing **strings**, either *equals* or *like* will perform about the same.

*Equals* will perform better if the column evaluated is indexed.

*LIKE* will give you more features: '%', '_', etc that will allow you to perform wider queries. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp for more info about *LIKE*

Comment: Yes. And if it's a common query, you should consider indexing that column, just like Abhik Chakraborty said

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE col='anything'` AND `SELECT col FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%anything%'` will return almost same answer,

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE col LIKE 'anything%'` this will return **end with string *anything***

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%anything'` this will return **start with string *anything***

Answer (score 0):

To match the word EXACTLY (because you are making a dictionary) you should use the first of the two queries:

```
 SELECT col FROM table WHERE col='anything'
```

The other query would match anything CONTAINING the string 'anything'. This would include 'fooanything' (not a word) and 'foo anything bar'. Which presumably you don't want.

So to answer your question:

> What is the advantage of using the LIKE clause in mysql?

It has the advantage of being able to match items which contain a string, but **in your use-case (a dictionary) it has no advantage whatsoever** and will infact return several matches when you want just one.

For example: Imagine you are looking up the term 'any'...

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%any%'
```

This query would return: 'any', 'many', 'anyway', 'anything', etc...

Answer (score 0):

The equals (=) operator is a "comparison operator compares two values for equality." In other words, in an SQL statement, It does not reply true unless both the values of the equation are equal.
Ex.
SELECT * FROM student WHERE roll = 10;

It will return Value only if the value of the roll is equal to 10.

Where as the LIKE operator "implements a pattern match comparison" that attempts to match "a string value against a pattern string containing wild-card characters." 
Ex.
SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE "%vat";

It will return all the rows where the name column values ending with string "vat".

SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE "Pra%";
It will return all the rows where the name column values starting with string "Pra".

SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE "%va%";
It will return all the rows where the name column values having the string "Pra".

NB:

```
1) When you know the exact value to comapre with the coloumn you may use =(equal) operator for Exact/Accurate Result.
    When you dont know the Compared value but you are able to remember part of the string or value you may use "LIKE" operator.

2) Equal(=), Comaprision Operator can be used in Integer/Float (Numeric) along with varchar/varchar2/text (String) but the Like Operatpor can be used only for varchar/varchar2/Text (String).
```