# How to sort the result of multiple queries alternatively?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union-all

I have a query made of three `select` clause like this:

```
select id, colors from table1
    union all
select id, numbers from table2 
    union all
select id, names from table3
```

Also here is the tables structure:

```
// table1               // table2              //table3
+----+--------+        +----+---------+        +----+-------+
| id | colors |        | id | numbers |        | id | names |
+----+--------+        +----+---------+        +----+-------+
| 1  | red    |        | 1  | ten     |        | 1  | jack  |
| 2  | green  |        | 2  | two     |        | 2  | peter |
| 3  | blue   |        | 3  | one     |        +----+-------+
| 4  | yellow |        | 4  | three   |
+----+--------+        | 5  | six     |
                       | 6  | five    |
                       +----+---------+
```

Now I want this order for the results:

```
+----+--------+
| id | colors |
+----+--------+
| 1  | red    |
| 2  | ten    |
| 3  | jack   |
| 4  | green  |
| 5  | two    |
| 6  | peter  |
| 7  | blue   |
| 8  | one    |
| 9  | yellow |
| 10 | three  |
| 11 | six    |
| 12 | five   |
+----+--------+
```

How can I implement that? (it should be noted, `order by 1,2,3` does not work for me)

Comment: You have 3 tables and you are selecting 3 columns for each table and to have them display them on one column you actually need 3 unions for each table. Could you provide some sample data along with the table ? In addition when you select without order by then its not guaranteed in which order they will be shown like you have for the first query result as  `red, green, blue, yellow`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty my question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do this

```
select @rn:=@rn+1 as id,colors from (
  (select @rn1:= @rn1+1 as rn,colors from table1,(select @rn1:=0)x order by id )
   union all 
  (select @rn2:= @rn2+1 as rn,numbers as colors from table2,(select @rn2:=0.5)x order by id)
   union all 
  (select @rn3:= @rn3+1 as rn,names as colors from table3,(select @rn3:=0.6)x order by id )
)x,(select @rn:=0)y order by rn ;
```

The idea is to assign a `rn` value for each table item and need to make sure that these values are always in ascending order

So if you run the query for each table you will have

```
mysql> select @rn1:= @rn1+1 as rn,colors from table1,(select @rn1:=0)x order by id;
+------+--------+
| rn   | colors |
+------+--------+
|    1 | red    |
|    2 | green  |
|    3 | blue   |
|    4 | yellow |
+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @rn2:= @rn2+1 as rn,numbers as colors from table2,(select @rn2:=0.5)x order by id;
+------+--------+
| rn   | colors |
+------+--------+
|  1.5 | ten    |
|  2.5 | two    |
|  3.5 | one    |
|  4.5 | three  |
|  5.5 | six    |
|  6.5 | five   |
+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @rn3:= @rn3+1 as rn,names as colors from table3,(select @rn3:=0.6)x order by id;
+------+--------+
| rn   | colors |
+------+--------+
|  1.6 | jack   |
|  2.6 | peter  |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here you can see `table1 rn` values are `1,2,3,....`
`table2` values are `1.5,2.5,3.5,....` 
`table3` values are `1.6,2.6,....`

so finally when you order the result with all rn it will be as

`1,1.5,1.6,2,2.5,2.6,....`

Comment: Your brain is praiseworthy ...! Every times I look at the answer I enjoy it. Well done pal! +1

Comment: just one question: when this is useful? `@rn:=@rn+1 as id`, and why `as id`? because there a real column named `id`

Comment: The reason is the above query is selecting data from already selected data. Now if you notice we are selecting only `color` and `rn` which is a row num we have calculated for each query, and outer select query is just another way of calculating some incremental number based on all the selected rows. If we happen to select ids in the inner query then you may get result with ids like `1,1,2,2,....` etc which does not look pretty well.